# Is the Flux equal to gradient in Vector analysis?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, uniform-continuity, heat-equation, gradient-flows

I am trying to get some appreciation of the concepts of flux and continuity equation in vector analysis. Let's keep ourselves to three spatial dimensions, $x, y$ and $z$

Assume the density is $u:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $u (x, y, z, t)$ is the density at $(x, y, z)$ and at time $t$.

Now, from some references, I got to know that flux measures the flow of the substance through a surface, as in electric current density etc. However, in some other places (particularly in a note dealing with differential equations), they model flux density as the gradient of $u(x, y, z, t)$, i.e.

$\mathbf{J}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\mathbf{i}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\mathbf{j}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\mathbf{k}$ is the flux, which is obviously a function of time.

I cannot conceptually reconcile these two apparently different definitions of flux.

Also, is my gradient representation of flux correct, or do we need some other parameter apart from the density function to characterise the flux? In other words, is the density enough to uniquely determine flux?

Answer (score 2):

The flux of a vector field $j$ through a surface $A$ is
$$
\Phi = \int\limits_{A=\partial V} j \cdot dA = 
\int\limits_V \text{div } j \,dV
$$
This is a scalar quantity, while a gradient is a vector.
Are you sure you did not misread some divergence for a gradient?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the flux density at a point, i.e the $j$ in your answer. The integral of course gives the total flux over a surface. Can you show me how to arrive at $j$ starting from $u$? I have edited the question.

Comment: Certain vector fields $j$ can be specified as gradient of a scalar field $u$: $j = \text{grad } u$, The resulting $j$ has no curl, so this is not possible for any $j$. You then arrive at  $\Phi  = \int \Delta u dV$.

Comment: Yeah, $j$ has to be conservative to be expressed as the gradient. But my question is can I always find $j$ from $u$ by taking the gradient? In other words, is it possible to define $j$ in terms of $u$?

Comment: Your $u$ and your $J$ seem to be particular physical quantities, material current and maybe concentration. So I think physical laws like conservation (no substance gets created or destroyed), get involved. I would need to understand the particular definitions here to make a statement.

Comment: So it is not pure mathematics, like the study of vector space etc.?

Comment: Pure maths is only the part to find a scalar $\phi$ field for $j=\text{grad }\phi$. There are integrability conditions, which is mostly $\text{curl } j = 0$ in three dimensions, the general version seems to be called Poincaré lemma. If this $\phi$ is your $u$ I do not know.